# Are there any disadvantages to using a working copy for your live website with SVN 1.7?

Tags: svn

I'm planning to publish our live site today and I've read that the best option is to use svn export to avoid populating the working copy with .svn files, however this is no longer an issue with SVN 1.7 as the metadata is stored in a single file. Seems to me that using a working copy is much better than exporting as updating the live site would be as simple as running 'svn update'. Is there any reason not to checkout a working copy and use export?

Comment: Good idea, although it's not actually a single file but it's a single .svn directory at the top level rather than .svn subdirectories in every directory.

Comment: @Rup, yes, I stand corrected, thanks.

Comment: If you do have .svn folders ensure their permissions are such that they aren't served up by the webserver.  I'd personally use tagged versions, so you don't accidentally `svn update` the site and pull in unexpected changes.  If on linux, use a symlink: `site_live -> site_1.00`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using svn update is that it's *too* easy to update your live site.  You might update to a version that doesn't work or is untested.

I'd recommend instead a hybrid approach - before releasing a new version, tag it, then svn switch the live site to that tag.

Obviously you still need to ensure you aren't serving up the root .svn directory.

Comment: Or run your site as a checkout of a separate stable branch and only merge / re-copy the branch when you're ready to update to it. But you can roll back your web code just as easily as you can update.

Answer (score 1):

Situation you're describing is a **serious security threat**.

As you might already know, Subversion stores its metafiles directly in working copy using `.svn` folders. Each such folder has file entries with the list of all directories having the same level as the corresponding `.svn` folder. In `.svn` folders you can also find information about repository location, filesizes, modification dates and **user logins**. In the case you're deploying your site simply by checking out working copy to the `htdocs` directory on the web-server, then using URL `site.com/.svn/entries` you will see not only project filestructure, but also list of authors, latest changes, link to the repository, etc.

You can also find `text-base` directory in each `.svn` folder. It contains latest revision of all files placed under version control. Files in `text-base` directory have `.svn-base` extension, it allows to send its content directly to the browser output without interpreting it on the server side. Namely, **it allows to see raw source code**!

Nevertheless, there are simple solutions to this problem.

**Apache:**

```
<Directory ~ ".*\.svn">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Directory>
```

**Nginx:**

```
location ~ /.svn/ {
    deny all;
}
```

To sum up, main disadvantage of such approach is that you should know about the threat and do not forget to prevent possibility of accessing `.svn` directories from web.

Comment: Please note that the OP talks explicitly about Subversion **1.7**, where this information is no longer true.

Comment: Are there any references in subversion documentation which is explicitly pointing out that this problem has been fixed?

Comment: For instance, the 1.7 [release notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng). Of course, it's still a good idea to prevent access to top level `.svn` directory, if it happens to be within the document root.